# SQL: How to query a junction table with compound keys by comparing rows and columns

Tags: mysql, junction-table

I have a Mysql junction table *user_connections* which maps the *users* table with the following columns: **user_from** and **user_to**, both are foreign keys in *users* table.

[image]

My logic is if **id1** sends a request to **id2**, in this case, that will be a pending request. The request will be considered aprroved only if **id2** accepts the request which will give the pattern above of (id1, id2) and (id2, id1) in the table (red box).

So my question is how can I query the *user_connections* table so I can get all the pending requests based on **id1** (blue box)

[image]

I have no idea how I can acheave this. So any help will be appriciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all the pending requests defined by your `user_connections` table, then you need to do a left outer join of the table with itself as follows:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table user_connections (
  user_from int,
  user_to int,
  primary key(user_from, user_to)
  );
  
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(1, 2);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(2, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(67, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(68, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(69, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(70, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select uc1.user_from, uc1.user_to from
user_connections uc1 left join
user_connections uc2 on uc2.user_from = uc1.user_to and uc2.user_to = uc1.user_from
where uc2.user_from is null;
```

| user_from | user_to |
| --- | --- |
| 67 | 1 |
| 68 | 1 |
| 69 | 1 |
| 70 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTVcX1VZNg3DpjFScezgYv/0)

For every (id1, id2) in the table we attempt to match it with a row with values (id2, id1). If there is no match, which is the case for pending requests, then the `uc2.user_from` and `uc2.user_to` columns will be null and so we just select from the left outer join those rows where `uc2.from_user` is null.

I created the db-fiddle for you, but this something that you should have done yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it and it works!